# How can I create a search bar in a folium map that can return any location (cities, towns, etc)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, openstreetmap, folium, searchbar, nominatim

I'm currently using Python and Jupyter Notebook (in visual studio code) and am trying to create a search bar like the one from this website: https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/geocoding-nominatim.html.

I have tried using the folium search plugin but can't figure out how to combine it with the Nominatim service like from the website I linked. I have found a lot of solutions using JavaScript but wouldn't know where to even begin with them.

I'm very new to all of this and am really struggling with this problem. Any help here would be great and apologies is there's an easy solution I am overlooking, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution to this issue, embarrassingly simple but for anyone wondering all you have to do is import the folium plugin geocode and add it to the map.

```
from folium.plugins import Geocoder

Geocoder().add_to(m)
```